How to Read from File1, Hash, the Write to File2
I am trying to write a Python script which you use one file as input, read a line, hash that word, the write to one line on the second new file, and continue this loop until you have a list of hashed words from the first file to the second file.
Here is my code:
import hashlib
import sys

def main():
    global word_list
    word_list = input("Input file name to pull words from: ")
    global hash_list
    hash_list = input("Filename to save as: ")
    hashing_algo = input("Select hashing algorithm: '1' (sha512), '2' (md5): ")
    
    answer = 'true'
    while answer == 'true':
        if hashing_algo == '1':
            sha512()
            sys.exit("Exiting software...")
        elif hashing_algo == '2':
            md5()
            sys.exit("Exiting software...")
        else:
            print('Select a valid option.')
            hashing_algo = input("Select hashing algorithm: '1' (sha512), '2' (md5): ")


def sha512():
    h = hashlib.sha512()
    f = open(word_list, 'r')
    g = open(hash_list, 'w')
    
    for word in f:
        # f.readlines()
        word = word.strip('\n')
        print(word)

        h.update(word.encode())
        hashed_word = h.hexdigest()
        g.write(hashed_word)
        # g.write("\n")
        

def md5():
    h = hashlib.md5()
    f = open(word_list, 'r')
    g = open(hash_list, 'w')
    
    for word in f:
        # f.readlines()
        word = word.strip('\n')
        print(word)

        h.update(word.encode())
        hashed_word = h.hexdigest()
        g.write(hashed_word)
        # g.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

It looks like it is hashing the first word, but it either does not has the second word or combines them and then it does not print them, hash by hash.

Why is g.write("\n") commented out? Also, you'll need to close both file handles. Can you please provide an example of inputs and outputs that you expect. See [mcve]

Note that even if this was working, you wouldn't be hashing the lines individually - the last hash output (for example) would be the hash of the entire input file, not just its last line.  You would need to create a new hashlib object for each line to get individual hashes - since there doesn't appear to be any way to reset and reuse the hash object.

here's a trivial example
NB: arguments are passed on the command line
chmod +x testhash.py #make sure the script is executable

cat testhash.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hashlib
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print('USAGE: inputfile outputfile hash (sha512 or md5)')
    sys.exit(1)
if sys.argv[3] == 'sha512':
    hash=hashlib.sha512()
elif sys.argv[3] == 'md5':
    hash=hashlib.md5()
else:
    print(f'ERROR:hash {sys.argv[3]} not one of sha512 or md5, aborting')
    sys.exit(1)

output=open(sys.argv[2], 'wt' )

with open(sys.argv[1]) as input:
    for record in input:
        record=record.strip('\n')
        hash.update(record.encode())
        print(f'processing :{record} {hash.hexdigest()}')
        print(hash.hexdigest(), file=output) # save

output.close()

#
# run
#
./testhash.py testhash.in testhash.out md5
processing :this 9e925e9341b490bfd3b4c4ca3b0c1ef2
processing :is f684b2f3d4218ee06dad551b3bb2074b
processing :not d3f34ecb81ee71177b097474c7d15841
processing :a 8a4dc3f940e7a44d5a11068e80a75848
processing :test 190e6ca2deccf866245de533459b1393

./testhash.py testhash.in testhash.out sha512
processing :this 1f4be9bd3c61e621ef43bb2e0a2d7836786f730e4e0e6aa546899bceab0571904dfc6efc94c1324b1a22ae446f0a995b533054b1dbd09d0cda03e0985786d59a
processing :is a23066c76d4b686d0fa8cc1675d0028b19511f575313421d7fe87fd337f672a4cda50ce0ca40b4f66ed2f834a668e60e3231086bbfde4be78b221506c2e0571b
processing :not c773aa16f46da065c7b72380a1be4fdfaf37b76faf0cc57860ae6cc8a34c773574b0ca10aaf9230c639ab3a0f775c6acc3293939d65053a284d28d120f71eafb
processing :a 39c1656dc0fb28d56638c3b4f45960eb48b4196c404ffbfd918fd7e083c45786e41b5071d2b7ce716ec2d73afddeba813aa02878d8f4409d73d8a130cb470d6a
processing :test b3c954cda3d86c43db9229c2f38ca609f167edc8062b87b29039b2b22c8565f6a51b14deeb2a74f1b4c3016cf2f9491cd29c6386e34c278c67e3cf7abfb0684b

hope this helps you on your coding journey, feel free to ignore/adapt
